# Expanding & Contracting adjacent UI objects within a view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a ViewController that is divided in 2 parts.

The top is a UIWebView
The bottom is a UITableView

Sometimes, there is no content required for the UITableView. So what I would like to do is have the UIWebView expand into the empty space the UITableView has relinquished.

I have Auto Layout Enabled with the following constraints:
The UIWebView is pinned to the top of the ViewController and the bottom of the UIWebView is pinned to the top of the UITableView

The UITableView is pinned to the bottom, with the top of the UITableView pinned to the bottom of the UIWebView.

When I set the hidden property of the UITableView to YES, it successfully hides the UITableView, but leaves a void where it once was, not expanding the UIVWebView.

What do you suggest?

Thanks

[EDIT]

The following code pushes down the tableView, but leaves a void behind it.

```
        CGRect newFrame = tableView.frame;
        newFrame.origin.y += 130;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

        tableView.frame = newFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

I won't "pull" the above UIWebView, it also happens to  hide the lower navigaiton bar.

Comment: You shouldn't set any frames when using auto layout. Your code also uses *very* old methods (`beginAnimations`, `commitAnimations`) that went out with iOS 4.

Comment: lol, it's what I'm used to, it does't seem to have been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding a view does not change its size or constraints, so the result you get is expected. You should probably have a height constraint on your table view, and make an IBOutlet to it. When there is no content in the table, modify the constant property of the constraint to make it 0.

```
self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
```

When there is content, you can calculate the height you need for the table view, and set the constant to that value, or some maximum value that you don't want to go beyond.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the constraints same as you given with addition to that -
Instead of hiding UITableView ,  remove it from superview and pinned bottom of UIWebView to bottom with low priority constraints so that when you remove UITableview this low priority constraints will work and it will expand your UIWebView.